# Need some ideas to achieve data marketplace through hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to create a data marketplace where a party can transact with other parties, agree on the set of terms and sell data from one to another.

Here data security is of utmost concern. A party makes data available on the hyperledger, this data should be secured and no one should get hold of it. If an interested party wants this data, they have to transact with data owner party and agree on the set of terms. Only then the interested party will get the data. And now only two parties should have hold of this data. Everyone else should not get hold of it.

I would like to know what components of hyperledger can be used here. I have an idea of private data concept in hyperledger, but not sure how and where it would fit.

Would love to hear some comments from experts regarding this.

Edit: 
I am thinking of using `private data` for data sharing securely whenever two parties agree for the transaction. And for that I am thinking of upgrading `chaincode` every time two parties agree on set of terms for data sharing. Only thing concerns me is that every endorsing peer needs to install and upgrade the new version of `chaincode` simultaneously and that could be undesirable, because data exchanges on this platform could be very frequent.

Comment: bit broad. what kind of data, what format will it be in and how do you plan to store it? Second, what does it mean "agree terms" ? what kind of terms ? are these terms long lived or short lived? Can access to data be revoked at any point? Is it a subscription based system, or one where you buy the data and own it forever, updates included? Can the data be updated? All these and probably more need to be clear

Comment: To answer your question, yes, it is a subscription based system, till subscription you get the data and its updates. I need opinions on where I should be storing the data (ledger maybe, but that doesn't seem like a good idea, or private data). Agree terms mean signing a contract or something, might include payment at a later point.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this, and get some idea

> [When to use a collection within a channel vs. a separate channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private-data/private-data.html#when-to-use-a-collection-within-a-channel-vs-a-separate-channel)

Comment: I am thinking of using private data for data sharing securely whenever two parties agree for the transaction. And for that I am thinking of upgrading chaincode every time two parties agree on set of terms for data sharing. Only thing concerns me is that everyone needs to install and upgrade the new version of chaincode simultaneously and that could be undesirable, because data exchanges on this platform could be very frequent.